# Symfony CreateFormBuilder ignores my Entity @Assert\Length

Tags: symfony, entity, assert, formbuilder

I have an entity User, which has $password with @Assert\Length(min=6)

```
/**
* @var string The hashed password
* @ORM\Column(type="string")
* @Assert\Length( min=6, minMessage="Password is too short (min 6 symbols)" )
*/
private $password;
```

I'm trying to generate a Login form using createFormBuilder

```
$LoginForm=$this->createFormBuilder(null,['data_class'=>User::class])
->add('email')
->add('password', ??? PasswordType::class ??? )
->getForm();
```

If I don't set the 'PasswordType::class' for my second field (in createFormBuilder), it generates HTML with "type='text'" field. The @Assert\Lenth seems to work fine (pattern=6, presents)

```
<input type="text" id="form_password" name="form[password]" required="required" pattern=".{6,}">
```

If I do set the 'PasswordType::class', the HTML field becomes "type='password'", but it completely forgets about minLength constraint...

```
<input type="password" id="form_password" name="form[password]" required="required">
```

So, at this point I have to choose between Text field (with minLength pattern) or Password field (which ignores my entity @Assert\Length) =|

===

UPD: about setting the constraints directly in the 'add()'

```
add('userName', TextType::class, ['constraints' => [new Length(['min' => 6])]])
```

generates empty (well, no constraints there) HTML aswell:

```
<input type="text" id="form_userName" name="form[userName]" required="required">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this alternative and by pass annotation

```
->add('password', PasswordType::class, [
     'constraints' => [
      new Length(['min' => 3]),
      ],
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sure I can, and most likely it will work. But set the 'constraints' in every single form doesn't seem to be a nice & clean way to keep everything in place. Besides the fact that 'my way' doesnt work makes me feel uncomfortable and I still would like to know the answer

Comment: Can you give me the sf version you're using so i can reproduice ?

Comment: Symfony 5.0.3 -- by the way, I just found out that your solution doesn't work for "PasswordType" -- "min=>3" doesnt do anything o_O

Comment: Sorry to hear that i tried the exact same thing worked like a charme with the same version i think you didn't use properly some use stamtement maybe please read the doc !

Answer (score 0):

The visibility of pattern option does not depend on form type field. If omit type field `add` method and assume that you already defined constraints on entity then constraint attributes will be available on html side.

```
/**
* @var string $userName
* @ORM\Column(type="string")
* @Assert\Length(min=6, minMessage="Username is too short (min 6 symbols)")
*/
private $userName;
```

So, if you declare your form type as follow:

```
$LoginForm=$this->createFormBuilder(null,['data_class'=>User::class])
    ->add('email')
    ->add('username')
    ->getForm();
```

Then you can see pattern attribute on input. But if you add any `FormType` field to `->add('username', TextType::class)` then pattern attribute will not available anymore. So, to add constraint to your form, add constraint directly to your form type.

```
  ->add('userName', TextType::class, [
            'constraints' => [
                new Length(['min' => 6]),
            ],
        ]);
```

For more information please have a look [Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/without_class.html#form-option-constraints) doc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But even if I set constraints directly, they dont work.I see only required="required" attribute on my(your) text field "userName", nothing else =|

Comment: It is useful to separate form type and put it into own file. So, if it possible create LoginFormType and update the contents of question. Afterwards, we can see broad-strokes.